# Validations using JavaScript in login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my code for admin login. I am using js files for validating from values but when I submit values using the submit button validation is not working.

```
 <html>
    <script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm" id="frm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" autocomplete="off">        

    <table>

    <tr>
    <td colspan = "2" align="center"><strong>Admin Login</strong></td>
    <tr>

    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input  type = "text" name = "username" value = ""  class="required username" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "password" value = "" class="required"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan = "2" ><input type = "submit" name = "btn" value = "Submit" /></td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: you need to post the data to the server and check if the database has a match. Otherwise, client side (javascript) validation is only for things like checking if an input box is empty or has invalid characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `validate()` method on form.

Add this in your script:

```
$('#frm').validate();
```

See [Doc](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-validate-forms-like-you-ve-never-validated-before)